# Lex Parsing for exponent

Tags: lex, ply

I am trying to parse a file the data looks like

```
size = [5e+09, 5e+09, 5e+09]
```

```
I have 'size OSQUARE NUMBER COMMA NUMBER COMMA NUMBER ESQUARE'
```

And NUMBER is defined in tokrules as

```
t_NUMBER  = r'[-]?[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]+([eE]-?[0-9]+)*'
```

But I get

```
Syntax error in input!
LexToken(ID,'e',6,113)
Illegal character '+'
Illegal character '+'
Illegal character '+'
```

What is wrong with my NUMBER definition?

I am using https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of your rule which matches exponents is

```
([eE]-?[0-9]+)*
```

Clearly, that won't match a `+`. It should be:

```
([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)*
```

Also, it will match 0 or more exponents, which is not correct. It should match 0 or 1:

```
([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```